# Calling a function inside a svg file on a object tag from javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

In my HTML page I got :

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  function mostrar(blo) {
   var str = "";
   ...
   window.document.tbl27svg.pinta(str);
}
```

And in some place in the same html page I have:

```
<object id="tbl27svg" data="../../imagenes/svg/tbl27.svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1100px" height="1000px" type="image/svg+xml"/>
```

And in the file tbl27.svg I need to call a function:

```
parent.pinta=pinta

function inicia(event){
    SVGDocument = event.target.ownerDocument;                                  
}       


    function pinta(strSVG){
    var nuevoNodo=parseXML(strSVG, document);
    if(document.getElementById('grafico1').childNodes.length>0){
        if(!document.getElementById('grafico2').childNodes.length>0)
            SVGDocument.getElementById("grafico2").appendChild(nuevoNodo);
    }else{
        SVGDocument.getElementById("grafico1").appendChild(nuevoNodo);
    }
}
```

So, I have tried several ways to call pinta() function on tbl27.svg file. But always I got a java script error: 
    "Object doesn’t support this property or method"

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to place `pinta()` function declaration before `window.document.tbl27svg.pinta(str);`:

```
<script>
  function pinta(){
    ...
  }

  function mostrar(blo) {
    var str = "";
    ...
    window.document.tbl27svg.pinta(str);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: `pinta()` is in the file: **tbl27.svg** and `window.document.tbl27svg.pinta(str);` is in the html page wich include this file in the tag `<object>`

Comment: Check if `var a = document.getElementById('tbl27svg').getSVGDocument();` returns a value.

Comment: @deimos1975 Also what browser are you using?

Comment: it returns undefined too. But I finally I have used something like as this in this page is made:
https://jwatt.org/svg/demos/scripting-across-object.html. And it seems to work. Thank you!